# Lagrange polinom in Visual C++ with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

How to create and print Lagrange polynomial in Visual C++ with using OpenGL library? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suggest you start on your own, and come back here if you have specific questions. Otherwise, it looks like "can you write my code for me?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be different approaches but guess one of the most simple to understand approaches might be something like this:

```
float f(float x)
{
    // calculate y for f(x) here
    return y;
}

void draw()
{
    glBegin();
    for(float x = 0; x < 10; x += 0.1)
        glVertex(x, f(x), 0);
    glEnd();
}
```

Please note that there are different ways to draw the graph (e.g. caching everything or passing an array etc.) with different performance culprits and advantages. In my example scaling etc. have to be done outside using view and projection matrix.